# Xcode 11 Won't Open New Editor Pane

Tags: xcode, ide, xcode11

So Xcode 11 [changed the way editor panes are added](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_release_notes#3318287) and removed. Ok, fine, I got used to it soon enough. But a few days after using the Xcode 11 GM build, the option to add an editor is suddenly disabled.

Could be a bug, could be a 'feature' that I've inadvertently triggered. Neither the menu, toolbar button nor shortcut (<kbd>^</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) will give me another editor (though they all did with the same build yesterday).

Any ideas?

[image]

(Note: this screenshot has the Navigator pane hidden for simplicity. Its presence/absence doesn't help with this issue)

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Ok, this is embarrassing. I was in a 'focus' mode and could only add editors after I had 'hidden focus'. There are a few ways to do this:

- View > Editor > Hide Focus
- Tap the 'arrows pointing at each other' icon in the top left of the editor toolbar
- <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↩︎</kbd>

[image: You need to 'hide focus' before you can add an editor in Xcode 11]

*ps. I was seriously tempted to delete my question when I realised how dumb I'd been, but I'm leaving it up as I suspect this UI quirk might also trip up others (let me know if it does, it'll help me feel like less of a fool)*

Comment: Always best to keep these "silly" questions with new tools, helps duplications.
This helped me thanks! I use shortcut keys all over Xcode, and 11 is now like playing the piano.

Comment: This was driving me INSANE. Thank you so much. This is terrible UI.

Comment: Thank you! Finally a solution! :D

Comment: It was driving me crazy too. I hate the new Xcode 11 editors changes. Thank you!

Comment: This really helped, Thanks!!

Comment: Come on Apple. A simple message when a click is detected on the "Add Editor" button that it's disabled for focus mode would have helped.

Comment: What even IS focus mode? (also thanks from me, this was not easy to find at all, so VERY valuable answer!)

Comment: I logged in to upvote this.  I can't believe anyone could possibly think this would be a good idea for a "feature".  I was working / typing, then could no longer open in a separate tab (for about two days).