# The button that allowed seeing two file side by side is now disabled in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode11

This is how it looks like

[image]

Now I'm using Xcode 11.1.

Everything was ok until I messed around with the project files, I guess. Also this feature works for the other projects but not with this one. How should I fix it?

Comment: Does option+click still work?

Comment: No it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this one might help you [Xcode 11 Won't Open New Editor Pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58054615/xcode-11-wont-open-new-editor-pane). It's because of Focus View enabled, actually.